# How do I return safely unwrapped optionals which are outside of their scope?

Tags: swift

I'm a noob, bear with me:

```
func createEmployeeCode() -> String? {
    let email = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email_Saved") as? String
    let employeeCode = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved") as? String

if let emailString = email,
    let employeeCodeString = employeeCode {
    return (emailString+employeeCodeString)
}

return (emailString+employeeCodeString) //ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier 'employeeCodeString' & Use of unresolved identifier 'emailString'
}
```

I understand the reason the error shows is because I'm trying to return something that is in a different scope here, but how else can I get the function to return the 2 strings together without the "Optional[...]" tag?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: NewCoder, what you're really looking for here is "guard" - see answer.  That's the "idiom" you'd use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sidenote: use `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:)`.)

The issue is that you can't know if those strings DO both exist or not--if they do, you already have a great `if let` that returns your answer. The question now is what do you want to do if one or both are `nil`? Maybe you'd like to return `nil` from the entire function. If so,

```
func createEmployeeCode() -> String? {
    let email = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email_Saved")
    let employeeCode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved")

    if let emailString = email,
        let employeeCodeString = employeeCode {
        return (emailString+employeeCodeString) //successful unwrapping, let's concatenate!
    }

    return nil //if one or both `if let`s fail, we end up here
}
```

Of course, you could do whatever you'd like in that "bad" case. Maybe you'd like to show whatever string you DO have. In that case:

```
func createEmployeeCode() -> String {
    let email = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email_Saved")
    let employeeCode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved")

    return (email ?? "") + (employeeCode ?? "") //this works in the "good" case, too, and uses the nil coalescing operator `??`
}
```

In this case, you can see that the return value is no longer optional. This is because even if neither string exists, it'll concatenate two empty strings. If this feels icky, you could keep your optional return value and do a quick check before returning:

```
if email == nil && employeeCode == nil { return nil }
```

Comment: You shouldn't just silence errors with `??`. Sure the compiler's not complaining, but now it's possible for you to `createEmployeeCode()` and get `""` back, which is clearly non-sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd expect it to be done in a normal production app

(You wouldn't do any of this in a normal production app! But this is the "idiom" you're looking for.)

```
func createCodeIfPossible() -> String? {

 guard let e = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email_Saved") else {
    print("serious problem, there's no email saved")
    // at this point the app is completely buggered, so give up
    return ""
 }

 guard let c = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved") else {
    print("serious problem, there's no code saved")
    // at this point the app is completely buggered, so give up
    return ""
 }

 return e + c
}
```

Do note that the return is largely meaningless - in the app in question, if one of the guards breaks you are "totally screwed". I'd probably just return a blank string (or more likely something like "name_error") since at this point the app architecture is hopelessly broken.

Comment: I'd recommend not adding the suffix `IfPossible` to a function unless it fails silently. It should be obvious to the developer based on the feedback from their IDE

Comment: @Chackle , yes, it's an interesting issue.  I am in the "code should be self documenting" camp, aka the "ridiculously long variable names" camp.  Sort of thing need beer to discuss.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
func createEmployeeCode() -> String {
    var finalString = String()
    if let email = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email_Saved"), let employeeCode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved") {
      finalString = email + employeeCode
     }

  return finalString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When assign back the values from `userDefaults` you've been trying to get as an `object` instead of `string`

```
func createEmployeeCode() -> String? {
    let email:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email_Saved") ?? ""
    let employeeCode:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved") ?? ""

    let emailString = "\(email)\(employeeCode)"

    return emialString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this depending on what you're trying to achieve.

---

If you always want to create an `employeeCode` (even if the code will be empty):

1. **Try using a "`nil` coalescing operator".**

```swift
func createEmployeeCode() -> String {
    let email = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email_Saved") as? String ?? ""
    let employeeCode = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved") as? String ?? ""

    return (email+employeeCode)
}
```

To explain what's happening here:

1. We're unwrapping `email`, if we don't find `email` then we default the value to an empty string, `""`.
2. We do the same with `employeeCode`.

This isn't a way I would solve every unwrap issue though, but it suits your usecase of `email` and `employeeCode` because you're always wanting to return something based on your original question. I've also changed the return type to non-optional.

---

If an employee code **must** always contain an `email` **and** and a `code` then we want to return `nil` if one of those isn't found.

2. **Try using the `guard` statement. The guard statement is perfect for validation and very readable:**

```swift
func createEmployeeCode() -> String? {
    guard let email = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email_Saved") as? String else { return nil }
    guard let employeeCode = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved") as? String else { return nil }

    return (email+employeeCode)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
func createEmployeeCode() -> String {
    let email = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email_Saved") as? String
    let employeeCode = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "employeeCode_Saved") as? String
    return [email, employeeCode].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "")
}
```

It will return email or employeeCode or email+employeeCode in case one of them is nil or both are present, or empty String in case if both are missed out!